# Graphql Codegen Wizard Terminated Unexpected

Tags: graphql-codegen

I am trying to use the GraphQL Codegen Wizard for my application.  I followed the installation instruction from this site: https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/installation

All the dependencies are successfully installed via npm with --legacy-peer-deps due to conflict.  When the time to run this command below, the script ended unexpectedly.  I did not get a chance to answer the question.

```
npx graphql-codegen init
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHaMJ.png)

**what am I doing wrong?**

System Details:

- OS Windows 10
- Node 16.15.1
- npm 8.11.0
- yarn 1.22.19
- Angular CLI 14.0.1
- GraphQL ^16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only fix that I've come up with is downgrading to version 2.10.0 of graphql code generator.

In your package.json make this change -> "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.10.0"

then npm install